# Datagridrow animation not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to animate a row when the value of a property `LastUpdated` is changed. The problem I have is that the animation only runs when I add a row to the grid, but when I change the property to test, the animation does not work. What is the problem?

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LastUpdated, Converter={StaticResource ValueHasChangedConverter}}"
                               Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard AutoReverse="True"
                                    RepeatBehavior="3x">
                            <ColorAnimation From="Transparent"
                                            Duration="00:00:0.5"
                                            To="{StaticResource AccentColor}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

public class ValueHasChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}

public class OrderStatusDataWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private DateTime _lastUpdated;
    public DateTime LastUpdated
    {
        get => _lastUpdated;
        set
        {
            _lastUpdated = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: The converter always returns true. Is that the intention? It also means that the value never changes from the binding's point of view.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Hi! Yes, that is the intention. I need to animate the row when that property changes, maybe I need to add something, but I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: But the converter will ALWAYS return true so the UI will never notice the change. In order for the UI to notice the change, the result of the converter has to change.